# need to sync PDA with OS Windows CE 5.0 to MS access database

Tags: windows-mobile

I have a Motorola MC3000 barcode scanner that runs Windows CE 5.0 operating system. I need to create a PDA form that would sync to a Microsoft Access database on a PC running XP.  Unfortunately, SprintDB Pro would not be suitable, because it only works with Windows Mobile operating systems.  please reccomend to me an app for under $100USD that would be compatible with Windows CE 5.0
thank you very much